# How To Append script and Div in one time from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one div, named `<div class="v7-music-detail-news">`. but i want to append div again and script inside a new div, but the page show nothing. please help me what i missed in my script.

here my script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'survey_frame';
    div.id = 'survey_frame';
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = "(function(d, h, s) {\
        var cont = d.getElementById('survey_frame_zLBexnZW');\
        var ifrm = d.createElement('iframe');\
        ifrm.src = 'http://www.someurl.com';\
        ifrm.style.width = '100%';\
        ifrm.style.height = '200px';\
        ifrm.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');\
        ifrm.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');\
        cont.appendChild(ifrm);\
        if (typeof iFrameResize == 'undefined') {\
            var ch = d.getElementsByTagName(h)[0];\
            js = d.createElement(s);\
            js.type = 'text/javascript';\
            js.src = 'http://www.someurl.com/iframeResizer.min.js';\
            ch.appendChild(js);\
            js.onload = iframe_resize;\
        } else {\
            iframe_resize();\
        }\
        function iframe_resize() {\
            iFrameResize({\
                log: true\
            }, '#survey_frame');\
        }\
    }(document, 'head', 'script'));";  
div.appendChild(script);
document.getElementById('v7-music-detail-news').appendChild(div);
    }
  </script>
```

here my div :

```
<div class = "v7-music-detail-news">
<!-- Here I want To Append new div and my script inside new div -->
</div>
```

Comment: `var cont = d.getElementById('survey_frame_zLBexnZW')` Is this supposed to reference the newly created div? If so, the id's don't match. And you'll probably have to append the div before the script so it can render, else the script won't be able to find the div. Last question, do you have a reason why you don't just write the script in a seperate file, but create it like this?

Comment: var cont = d.getElementById('survey_frame_zLBexnZW') not reference the newly created div . but thats my mistake, i've been rename that script with survey_frame , still show nothing. In my browser inspector , the new div and script successfully created , but script inside new div not running. i create script like this to simplify my work , that things is save my time a lot

Comment: You might have to use `.textContent` instead of `.text`, but I'd really advice to put the script in a seperate file and just set the src of the newly created script tag. Creating scripts like this will trigger eval, which might cause security issues if ppl want to hack your site. And loading an external script not only guarantees that the DOM elements the script uses are ready, it also makes the script execute immediately when it's loaded. Copy/pasting the script into a dfiferent file only takes like 1-2 mins.

Comment: okay, thanks for your suggest

Comment: Where is your script tag relative to your div. I don't see anything delaying execution, so if the script is first it's executing before `v7-music-detail-news` exists.

Comment: i've been put the script in a seperate file , and work 100% . thanks for your  answer